# OpenTest : How to integrate Opentest with linux jenkins server?

Tags: opentest

I need assistance on OpenTest for below scenario:
My code is in Aws-Code-Commit repository and my Jenkins is installed in one of the ec2 instance. Now I want to run all my OpenTest test-cases in a Jenkins job and publish the results. I have seen the Jenkins integration tutorial but still getting stuck in Opentest integration with remote Linux Jenkins instance.
I have no clue on how to start the server and actor in my Linux Jenkins instance and how can I execute my test-cases.

Can you help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to trigger a bash script file which will then execute the node and opentest commands to run your tests. If this answer seems obvious but you still have questions, can you clarify how far along in the process you are stuck?